# Could anyone explain why the only highestValue is plotting?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to capture the highest and lowest values of the day 90 minutes before market open.
I plotted the highest value with no problem, but nothing seems to work for getting the lowest value.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Range before open", overlay=true)

inTimeRange = time("1", "1359-1530:23456", "GMT+1")

var float highestValue = na
var float lowestValue = na

if inTimeRange
    if high > highestValue or na(highestValue)
        highestValue := high
    
    if low < lowestValue or na(lowestValue)
        lowestValue := low

high_low_range_middle = (highestValue + lowestValue) / 2
high_low_range = highestValue - lowestValue
range_offset = high_low_range / 3
upper_bound = highestValue + range_offset
lower_bound = lowestValue - range_offset

plot(highestValue, title="High of the Day (14:00-15:30)", color=color.white, linewidth=1)
plot(lowestValue, title="Low of the Day (14:00-15:30)", color=color.white, linewidth=1)
plot(high_low_range_middle, title="Middle of the Day (14:00-15:30)", color=color.white, linewidth=1)
plot(upper_bound, title="Upper bound of the Day (14:00-15:30)", color=color.white, linewidth=1)
plot(lower_bound, title="Lower bound of the Day (14:00-15:30)", color=color.white, linewidth=1)
```

[image: Image of chart]

I have not found any solutions yet.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Market was trading around all-time-high but lows are outside of scope of the image.
Problem could be solved by adding this code (in between stars **).

```
if inTimeRange
    if high > highestValue or na(highestValue)
        highestValue := high
    
    if low < lowestValue or na(lowestValue)
        lowestValue := low

**if na(inTimeRange[1]) and not na(inTimeRange)
    highestValue := high
    lowestValue := low**
```

[image: Result]